# Application Debugger for Windows 7 x64

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

Could you please recommend me a good **application level debugger for Windows 7 x64?**  It is not needed to debug 64-bit applications; it must only run reliably within a 64-bit environment.

I am searching for something like **OllyDbg** (http://www.ollydbg.de/). However, the problem with OllyDbg is that it is not yet ported for Windows 7 x64.

*This has been tried:*

- **SoftICE** (does not work for Win7 x64)
- **Syser** (it was giving me error messages after installation)
- **WinDBG** (this one looked too complex and slow to learn. I did not like floating windows all around)
- **IDA pro** (this one did not allow me to debug application. It only listed the structure graph)
- **OllyDBG** (after loading the application, it terminates it immediately. Probably a result of compatibility. I also checked emulating Windows XP SP3, but not help at all)

It is required to run the application in real time, and trace it in assembly language.

Comment: I know WinDBG is painful to learn, but it is what the pros use. Have a look at this blog for.. eh.. inspiration.. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/

Comment: @MikeEast: Hi Mike, if I understand correctly, the webpage displays solving complex problems with WinDBG... interesting to see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both OllyDbg 1.10 and IDA pro works fine in Win7 x64.

For OllyDbg use [Stealth64](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.2425) plugin.

Comment: @Abyx: +1 for very valuable information. Are you sure, that OllyDBG 1.10 runs under Win7 x64? It is true, that I could launch it, but I got the debugged process terminated on code EP. With IDA Pro, I had problem, that the code flow diagram does not display jumps, and crashes on the first box with error code: **start endp ; sp-analysis failed**

Comment: I've just wrote very simple program that simply displays output on program console. The program crashed, after I opened it in OllyDBG 1.1 under Windows 7 x64. Maybe, I am doing something wrong or I haven't set proper settings.

Comment: For example, OllyDBG 2.01b was able to run the application and start debugging, but it does not have plug-ins functionality yet implemented. Since some plug-ins are absolutely necessary to me, I can not use it at this moment.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori : Updated the answer. In IDA press [space] button. Function graph hasn't any relation to debugger.

Comment: @Abyx: After trying too many combinations, I have ended with Windows XP Virtual Machine and OllyDBG running on it. This is just fabulous plug-in, and I am really thankful for it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have to say, the Stealth64 did not work well to me on OllyDBG 1.10 and Windows 7 x64. I have opened the same application for debugging in Virtual Windows XP 32bit and OllyDBG 1.10, vs. Windows 7 64bit and OllyDBG 1.10 + Stealth64. Despite I was able to open and debut application on XP, I was not able to do so on Win 7. The most usual errors I got were: "Don't know how to continue, because memory at address 00000000 is not readable. Try to change EIP or pass exception to the program", or I simply got the process terminated at the beginning.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori : configure it.

Comment: @Abyx how did you work with 64-bit application using OllyDbg ??

Comment: @AminM please read the question, it's about 32-bit applications on 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Abyx i read,my problem is my windows OS(and it applications) is 64 bit but my ollydbg is 32 bit!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is decent as a program-binary debugger, it's excellent for programs with .pdb information and source code.  Only the advanced version of IdaPro works on 64-bit OS's.  From their website:

IDA Pro Standard supports the following families (64-bit analysis is possible only with the Advanced Edition)